# Check value if empty from multiple id on input type text

Tags: jquery, validation, onclick

I have multiple inputs in a form which are generated with a loop.

**E.X:**

```
<form>
    <input type="text" id="name_1" name="name_1" />
    <input type="text" id="address_1" name="address_1" />
    <input type="text" id="date_1" name="date_1" />
    <input type="text" id="name_2" name="name_2" />
    <input type="text" id="address_2" name="address_2" />
    <input type="text" id="date_2" name="date_2" />
    <input type="text" id="name_3" name="name_3" />
    <input type="text" id="address_3" name="address_3" />
    <input type="text" id="date_3" name="date_3" />
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

When event submit click, only `id=name_` and `id=address_` will validate if empty show the alert not the `id=date_`

can doing this with jQuery?

Comment: yes. It can also be done with plain JavaScript. What have you tried that isn't working?

Comment: Give the name as array for name, address and date. Using jquery each function you can validate for name and address.

Comment: I believe what your asking for is the possibility of form validation with jquery in your code (form) given above. It should be possible.

Comment: i mean when it submit click, it will validate only input with id=name_ and id=address_
the id=date_ will not be validate, can do this with just using selector like the answer below?

Comment: Sorry, but it work's when only `name=name_1` and `name=address_1`, the rest can still submit

Answer (score 1):

```
if($("input[name^='name_']" ).val()=="")
{ // alert for "name_" input
return false ;
}

if($("input[name^='address_']" ).val()=="")
{ // alert for "address_" input
return false ;
}
```

reference [**attribute start with selector**](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)

Comment: i will choose this answer because it give me some basic reference source. Thank you :)

Comment: Sorry, but it work's when only name=name_1 and name=address_1, the rest can still submit

Comment: use return false by this form not submit when every thing is correct then use return true  i give hint dear you can use your logical approach too achive your goal

Comment: have u got your solution i have provided you working link @KhalifaEsha

Comment: not yet, I mean because of the dynamic input looping, and which examined only the `id` / `name` of the `name` and `address`

Answer (score 1):

Try this

JS

```
function validatevalue()
{
    if($("input[id^='date_']" ).val()=="")
    { 
        alert("Date");
        return false;
    }

    if($("input[id^='name_']" ).val()=="")
    { 
        alert("name");
         return false;
     }
     return true;
}
```

HTML

```
<input type="text" id="name_1" name="name_1" />
<input type="text" id="address_1" name="address_1" />
<input type="text" id="date_1" name="date_1" />
<input type="text" id="name_2" name="name_2" />
<input type="text" id="address_2" name="address_2" />
<input type="text" id="date_2" name="date_2" />
<input type="text" id="name_3" name="name_3" />
<input type="text" id="address_3" name="address_3" />
<input type="text" id="date_3" name="date_3" />
<input type="submit" value="submit" onclick="return validatevalue();" />
```

Updated Answer

```
function validatevalue()
{
    $('input').each(function(){
        if($(this).val()==""){
            alert("Fill Value");
            return false;
        }
    });
     return true;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qrqJ3/)

[Updated Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qrqJ3/11/)

Comment: Sorry, but it work's when only name=name_1 and name=address_1, the rest can still submit

Comment: Can you explain in details, in your question, you are telling only about these.

Comment: I have provided generic solution please check, I will update your fiddle also

Answer (score 1):

assign a same class ie, `validateInput` to each input and then use:

```
function validatevalue()
{
  $( "input.validateInput" ).each(function( index ) {
     if($(this).val() =="" )
     {
         if(!this.id.contains('date')){
            alert('Please fill the required information.');
             return false;
         }
     }
  });
}
```

[Here is JsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qrqJ3/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [jQuery Validation Plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org/) to perform this task.

Assuming that you are well versed with jQuery, you can add the following rules within the `$(document).ready()`. Prior to that here are the assumptions:

1. The id of your `form` object is `myform`

Having made these above assumptions; within `document.ready` do the following as  aprt of initialization:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$("#myform").validate({
    rules : { name_1 : "required", address_1 : "required" },
    messages : {name_1 : "Enter your name.", address_1 : "Enter your address"}

  });
});
```

Note that you would need to include **jquery.validate.js** within your page.

The advantage of using jQuery validation is that, it allows you to specify multiple validation rules on all elements within a form. Also, you can specify additional validation criteria such as specifying the minimum length of content within a text field, whether a particular check box is checked or not etc... It also ensures that you have cross-browser validation logic.